# SQL Agent job step fails after upgrading to Powershell 5

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, powershell

I've not seen this issue discussed on the web, and have searched far and wide. I have a brand new HP DL380 running SQL Server 2008R2 standard. It's not yet in production, and I'm testing SQL Agent jobs. The server is running Windows Server 2012R2 Standard, and came with Powershell 4 installed.

I upgraded to Windows Management Framework 5 (Powershell 5), ran the first script through Powershell ISE and everything was ok. Then I executed the same script from SQL Agent and it failed with: "The term 'New-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

The job step is a CmdExec type, uses a proxy account, and calls powershell.exe to execute the script. If I make the proxy account a member of the local administrators group it works. If I roll back to Powershell 4 it works (no other changes). But if I again upgrade to Powershell 5, it fails.

It's obviously some type of permissions issue, but there is no clue as to what part of the security universe to investigate.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please post command you have used in SQL agent job step?

Comment: @sqlprodba - thanks for your help. The command is: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "D:\dbsoftware\Insert-Records.ps1 -InsertType LogCopyOnly"

Comment: Can you try running job step as powershell type to see what happens?

Comment: Although it would be interesting to see how that turns out, I need a solution for CmdExec job steps.

Comment: You need to post the script or contents of "Insert-Records.ps1" in order for us to help, or even try to reproduce the issue.